# Value of variable changes after applying the same method twice Firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a Firebase database that I want to retrieve the friend ID from. This works perfectly as I'm getting the right value when logging the friendUserId in the for loop. However, the log at the end of the method only displays the right value after executing the method twice. At first it displays "s", the second time it displays the string that I want. I feel like it has got something to do with processing time of the query, but I'm not sure really. How do I solve this?

```
public String friendUserId="s";


public void checkUserExistence() {
    mDatabase.child("Users")
            .orderByChild("username")
            .equalTo(EmailSearchQuery)
            .addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                    if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {
                        for (DataSnapshot childSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                            friendUserId = childSnapshot.getKey();
                            Log.d("dwada",friendUserId);

                        }
                    } else
                        Toast.makeText(AddAFriend.this, "Gebruiker niet gevonden", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError firebaseError) {
                    Log.e("MainActivity", "onCancelled", firebaseError.toException());
                }
            });

Log.d("dwada",friendUserId);
}
```

Comment: `onDataChange` will be called after `checkUserExistence` ended.

Comment: I figured out how to fix it already, thanks!